# Anything wrong with using Java for a front end and Excel or Access for the database backend?

Tags: java

Need to manage a large database with 20,000 rows of data and 20 columns of data (excel). I only know JAVA and wanted to program a front end that makes it easier to manage the spreadsheet and collate data. I also wanted to use JAVA to connect a few web services and link to a few 3rd party application's API for email and other things.

Is there anything wrong with using excel or access to hold the database (stored locally on an internal server)? It doesn't need to hookup to the internet to pull or push data. The only real thing I'm concerned about is speed. Is there a better database solution that is significantly faster?

---

EDIT: How do I store a local MYSQL database? I need to store everything locally and nothing on the internet.

Comment: why not mysql or equivalent?

Comment: If it is a ready only data, then you can go ahead with excel otherwise, I would suggest to use a proper database as it helps you in better data/transaction management

Comment: Excel and Access scale very badly. Using a real relational database would be much more appropriate.

Comment: Access as a backend, why not if you like having it hard. But _Excel_?

Answer (score 4):

Excel is an excellent tool to analyze data.  But not to store and manage data, which is what you are looking for.

In my experience, any time that someone says "We can manage the data just with Excel", within a month's time it'll be regretted.

One problem with managing the data with Excel is that as the data grows (and it always grows) it becomes harder to manage, and you'll have more weird workarounds that you'll have to work with to manage the data.

Another problem is that once you start coding assuming you'll be using excel as a backend, you start making certain assumptions about how the data looks, and the second someone edits the excel file manually you'll be in deep trouble.

I recommend you invest some time in learning how to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  Its not too steep of a learning curve, and it will let you do so much more than excel while letting you be so much safer.  If you want, you can then code an "export to excel" feature, but you should avoid using excel as your data store.

Comment: How do I store mysql locally? The data cannot be stored on the internet and I would like to be able to store whatever database I use on a server's hard drive (or my hard drive)

Comment: You could use mysql to store the data locally, but I recommend you use SQLite.  Mysql is a full database and might be an overkill for what you want, while SQLite is really a library that writes to a file in a very organized and smart way.  See this tutorial:
http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectSQLite.do

Comment: In my experience, any time that someone says "We can manage the data just with Excel", within a month's time it'll be regretted. - I confirm

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, MS Access via JDBC.ODBC is a PITA. First, you have very limited features (query language itself, and you can't prepare statements!) and second, it is terribly slow in comparison to most, if not all other systems with JDBC support. Furthermore, I had problems with the Access User Authentication (had to turn it off manually in exclusive mode).

If you want something that works with just a DB Driver and a file, like MS Access, go for an embedded SQL Server such as [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) (useful, Java based features) or [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) (portable). Otherwise, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, etc. would also do the job, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-off project, the kind that you write it, use it, then forget it? Then it might be easiest to just learn some VB Script (or whatever language Excel supports) and use Excel's feature's to your advantage and not have to mess with writing code to enable Java to communicate with the data in it's current format.

Everyone that is suggesting to use a database over Access/Excel doesn't seem to mention that you'll also need to write code to migrate the data from Excel to the database. At 20,000 entries you're not going to migrate by hand. If you keep getting new data, or updates to the data in Excel format, then you'll need to run your import job everytime the data changes if you choose the DB route. If whoever/whatever is supplying the data can change to a more SQL-friendly format then a database becomes much more viable.

I would expect Java and a DB will be more performance oriented than working directly in Excel, but make sure that you don't spend so much extra effort getting that to work compared to just writing some quick and just letting Excel spin for a bit while you make a sandwhich.

Answer (score -1):

Since you already know Java, and seem to want to avoid sql, you can still use sqlite but ease your learning curve by using an ORM. I suggest ORMLite: http://ormlite.com/ which will allow you to construct and deal with your database using Java and not (necessarily) having to deal with sql.